# Dúvida em array método each_with_index

Tags: array, ruby

Ao executar o método abaixo ele imprime literalmente `0 x 2`, `1 x 4`. etc.

Preciso achar uma solução para colocar imprimir somente o resultado do produto do valor pelo índice.

Meu código atual:

```
array = [2,4,6,8]

array.each_with_index {|value, index| puts "#{index} * #{value}"; }
```

Comment: Importante você `EDITAR` esta pergunta, explicando-a de forma clara, objetiva e direta, enfatizando a dificuldade encontrada. Além disso, nos forneça um [Exemplo mínimo, completo e verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) do problema, junto com sua tentativa de resolução. E mais, sugiro a leitura do [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8045/guia-de-sobreviv%C3%AAncia-do-stack-overflow-em-portugu%C3%AAs) para entender melhor o funcionamento da plataforma, evitando maiores frustrações.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ele está fazendo isso pois você está mandando ele fazer isso.

Como o `*` está entre `""` ele considera uma `string` e não uma operação matematica.

Uma forma de você resolver isso é colocar tudo em um só `#{}`, vai ficar assim o código:

```rb
array = [2,4,6,8]

array.each_with_index {|value, index| puts "#{index * value}";} #aqui eu retirei um  }, # e o {
```

Caso queira armazenar os resultados em um `array`, para utilizalos depois, uma das maneiras de fazer isso é assim:

```rb
array = [2,4,6,8]
otherArray = []

array.each_with_index {|value, index| otherArray[index] = index * value; } 

puts otherArray
```

Veja funcionando no [repl.it](https://repl.it/@Cdigodede/LastHighMosaic#main.rb) os dois exemplos

Comment: Obrigada pela resposta, tenho mais uma dúvida por exemplo tenho esse array de cima que esta fazendo essa operação de multiplicação se eu quiser colocar o resultado #{index * value}";} em um novo array, como eu poderia fazer isso?

Comment: ve se esse [link](https://guru-sp.github.io/tutorial_ruby/arrays-ruby.html) te ajuda.

Comment: Se esta resposta resolveu o seu problema e não restou nenhuma dúvida, marque-a como correta/aceita ao clicar no "✅" que está ao lado dela, o que também marca a sua pergunta como resolvida. Se preferir a outra resposta, pode marcá-la como correta/aceita, mas apenas uma resposta pode ser marcada dessa forma, você ainda pode clicar na setinha para cima se gostou da pergunta, essa é a forma de dizermos obrigado aqui no site. Se ainda te resta alguma dúvida ou gostaria de maiores esclarecimentos, fique a vontade para comentar. 

Comment: Editei a resposta adicionando uma das maneiras de fazer isso

Comment: Obrigada pela ajuda de coração, por mais pessoas como voce no mundo

Answer (score 2):

Você está imprimindo a "conta" em si (e não o resultado do produto) porque os termos estão interpolados dentro de uma string:

> ```
> puts "#{index} * #{value}"
> ```

Irá imprimir, para cada iteração, o valor do índice, seguido de um asterisco entre espaços, com o valor ao final. Você não está, de fato, avaliando os operandos. No trecho acima, o `*` não se trata do operador de multiplicação, é apenas uma parte da string.

Nesse caso como você só quer o resultado, não faz sequer sentido usar interpolação. Só imprima o resultado da operação. Assim:

```
array = [2, 4, 6, 8]

array.each_with_index do |value, index|
  puts index * value
end
```

Acima, o `*` está, de fato, fazendo o papel de operador de multiplicação e, portanto, os resultados do produto serão corretamente avaliados e impressos.

A interpolação, pois, só faria sentido se você quisesse mostrar cada "conta armada", seguida de seu respectivo resultado:

```rb
array = [2, 4, 6, 8]

array.each_with_index do |value, index|
  puts "#{index} * #{value} = #{index * value}"
end
```

<sup>Veja os dois exemplos funcionando no **[Repl.it](https://repl.it/@lffg/SOpt-476168#main.rb)**.</sup>